# Changing state with setState

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get setState to work with no luck. This is the following code

```js
class test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      invalid: null,
    };
  }

  boolTest = () => {
    this.setState({ invalid: true });
  };

  // ...
}
```

This is how i'm calling the function inside a form field

```js
invalid={this.boolTest}
```

This is the error output

> Error: Property "invalid" must be true, false or null; got "undefined"
>   (undefined)
>
> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually
>   means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Comment: You are giving the `boolTest` function to the `invalid` prop. Is that really what you want? Maybe you should give it to the `onChange` prop or something similar just for experimentation.

Comment: I believe so. 'invalid' is a property of a form component that i'm using. I'll experiment with onChange.

Answer (score 2):

`boolTest` is a function that doesn't actually return a value that you'd be able to use. You actually want to do:

```
invalid={this.state.invalid}
```

or as a clearer example:

```
const { invalid } = this.state;

return (
  <>
    <Button onClick={this.boolTest}
    <Component invalid={invalid} />
  </>
)
```